# CMake - change current directory ( for example: project/build ) from CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: linux, bash, cmake

I'm building project with CMake. While configuration and building I'm in directory project/build . How can I change the directory in CMake and execute a bash script from another directory.

execute_process( COMMAND cd ../ )  - doesn't work. When I execute this CMake doesn't change its directory and I'm again in project/build.

Comment: How about putting the bash script and cd on the same execute_process? I mean something like execute_process( COMMAND "cd ../  && mybashscript" )

Answer (score 16):

The `WORKING_DIRECTORY` directive of the `execute_process` command lets you directly specify the directory the script is to be run from.

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/script.sh args
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Answer (score 2):

With `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` you get the source path. Executing a binary from the source directory would be

```
execute_process(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/myscript.sh)
```

If you need to handle files from the build directory you have to add them like

```
execute_process(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/myscript.sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/input.txt)
```

Overall the variables `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` are very helpful. You can find a more complete list at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables